# Ruby on Rails Routing match parameters not showing up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have the following routes

```
     match 'tracks/:id/entire_graph'=> "tracks#entire_graph", :as => "entire_graph"
  match 'tracks/:id/entire_graph/:rid'=> "tracks#entire_graph", :as => "entire_graph2"
  match 'tracks/:id/:rid' =>  "tracks#blahh", :as => "refer_your_friends"

  resources :tracks

  match '/auth/:provider/callback' => 'authentications#create'
  match '/auth/failure' => 'authentications#failure'
  match '/tracks/:id/:rid/facebookpost' => 'tracks#facebook_post', :as => "facebook_post_track"
  match '/tracks/:id/:rid/twitterpost' => 'tracks#twitter_post', :as => "twitter_post_track"
  resources :authentications
```

My problem is regarding the 'tracks/:id/:rid'  route.

I am trying to call it like this:  'tracks/9/15'

I get a value for params[:id], but params[:rid] = nil, and I cannot figure out why.

Comment: Can you try doing this match 'tracks/:id/refer_your_friends/:rid' =>  "tracks#blahh", :as => "refer_your_friends" and see if its working?

Comment: I'd try two things; first, using a [segment constraint](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#segment-constraints) to further restrict matching, and re-ordering the matchers--without checking I'm guessing there's a precedence issue, although it doesn't quite match the symptoms if you're getting to the right controller method--is the snippet a cut-and-paste?